# Laravel: Update on same page not working

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update

So im quite new to Laravel and im trying to update a specific database entry with an update function. I used this function before and it always worked fine but not this time and I can't figure out what the problem is.

I guess it has something to do with that fact that im trying to update an entry on the same page? 
Here is my Code:

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Player $player)
{
    request()->validate([
        'points' => 'required'
    ]);

    $player->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('games.index')
        ->with('erfolgreich','Frage wurde erfolgreich geändert!');
}
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('games.update',$player->id) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
            <input type="number" value="{{ $player->points }}" name="points" id="pointcounter">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-3">Nächste Frage &raquo;</button>
        </form>
```

Im trying to create a simple quiz with laravel and later on I want the code to add the number from my input-field to the points-column in my database.
Does someone know why it's not working? I don't get an php error it just won't update my database :(

Since if have basically no idea what im doing here is my git repository if it helps:

https://github.com/dirtypaulmfz/Quiztopher.git

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does your model have `points` in `$fillable` array?

Comment: Yes, my Model looks like this: 

protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'quiz', 'points'
    ];

Comment: Can you check that you actually get the player in the controller with `dd($player)`? If you do, can you check that `$request->points` is not empty as well?

Comment: I'm not rellay sure whats suppose to be showing :D Im sorry. 

`Player {#219 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}`

Comment: There's the problem, your `$player` is empty. Btw, can you tell me why you currently have `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('games.update',$player->id + 1) }}">` in your view? Why `+ 1` next to `$player->id`? (from the github source)

Comment: Ye well that was my workaround for the fact that it somehow always showed the latest user - 1 when i don't use the +1.. As I said im quite new to Laravel and PHP in general. I started like one week ago and it's an university project .. My deadline is on Monday that's why I tried to make everything work as good as I can at this point. I wouldn't be surprised if I had to change a whole lot to fix a couple of issues I have atm.. The current version you're looking at is my reduced version, got another, bigger one in my branches on github :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your routes you defined this is `Route::resource('games', 'GamesController')`. Which will expect a model named `Game` for model binding. It won't recognize the `$player Player`.

So the quick solution is not to use model binding:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    request()->validate([
        'points' => 'required'
    ]);

    Player::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());

    // Or, to reduce to 1 query:
    // Player::where('id', $id)->update($request->only('points'));

    return redirect()->route('games.index')
        ->with('erfolgreich','Frage wurde erfolgreich geändert!');
}
```

But since you're not actually building a CRUD application, I would just not use the `Route::resource` method in my routes, but explicitly bind them instead.

So changing `Route::resource('games', 'GamesController');` to:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'games', 'as' => 'games.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'GamesController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/winner', 'GamesController@winner');
    Route::post('/', 'GamesController@store')->name('store');
    Route::put('{player}', 'GamesController@update')->name('update');
});
```

^ That way you don't need to change anything in your controller. The difference is that `Route::put('{player}')` will now expect a `Player` model and not a `Game` model.

Comment: Happy to help :)